# redirect @login-required for specific pages

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

In Django, I have in my files:

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'frontpage'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'myaccount'
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if not len(cart):
        return redirect('cart_view')
...more code...
```

my question is simple...
How do I set the `@login_required`, so that instead of the `myaccount` page being the redirect URL, I can send it back to `checkout` page?

In other words, where can I override LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL when needed?

Thank you,

Comment: try to add `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'checkout' %}" />` inside the `<form></form>` tags of your POST html or for your `GET` request add `?next={% url 'checkout' %}` parameter to the url. Djano should look for the `next` key and'll redirect to this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if request.user.is_authenticated:` method for user is logged in or not, if not logged in then `redirect` on checkout `URL`

remove `@login_required` decorator and check mannualy, user is logged in or not like this...

##### views.py

```
def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart = Cart(request)

        if not len(cart):
            return redirect('cart_view')
        ...more code...
    else:
        return redirect('checkout')
```

Comment: the only thing I can see there as an issue, is if I need to authenticate.  this code puts me in a loop `if not authenticated redirect ('checkout')`....how do I send to login and return to checkout?  Thanks.